# An error with some simple lists and if statements in python

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a code in python 3 but I get an error on the following line of code:

```
if x > blacks[i*2] and y < blacks[(i*2)+1] and ((x - blacks[i*2]) / (blacks[(i*2)+1]-y) <= 1 :
```

I don't think the problem is related with the rest of the code because I get the error even when I try using this 'if statement' in a very simple code:

```
blacks = [0,0,0,0,0]
i = 1
x = 0
y = 0
if x > blacks[i*2] and y < blacks[(i*2)+1] and ((x - blacks[i*2]) / (blacks[(i*2)+1]-y) <= 1 :
    blacks[i * 2] = blacks[i * 2]+4
    blacks[(i * 2) + 1] = blacks[(i * 2)+1] - 2
```

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is right here

`(x - blacks[i*2]) / (blacks[(i*2)+1]-y)`

Both of those values on either side of the `/` evaluate to 0, therefore you're dividing 0 by 0.

Comment: The error doesn't come from here even if the parentheses issue is fixed because both `x > blacks[i*2]` and `y < blacks[(i*2)+1]` evaluate to `False` (`0 < 0` is `False`), so `(x - blacks[i*2]) / (blacks[(i*2)+1]-y) <= 1` never gets to be evaluated and would not cause a division by zero error.

Comment: Well without knowing what the error actually is, the best we can do is speculate. Regardless of whether it makes it to that point or not, it's still going to cause problems in the future.

Comment: The code, as it is written by the OP, has only one error, and that is that it's missing a parentheses. It isn't a speculation, but a fact. Your answer here on the other hand is a speculation because as it is currently written, the division by zero error simply would not happen.

Comment: The point is that *nothing* would happen. There are more problems here than a missing `)`

Comment: The point is that the OP states that he got an error from the code he posted, and that is **something** that does happen--a syntax error of a missing parentheses. The division by zero error, on the other hand, is something that does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the right parentheses at the end of the expression in the `if` statement, or rather you have an extra left parentheses before `(x - blacks[i*2])`, which should be corrected as follows:

```
blacks = [0,0,0,0,0]
i = 1
x = 0
y = 0
if x > blacks[i*2] and y < blacks[(i*2)+1] and (x - blacks[i*2]) / (blacks[(i*2)+1]-y) <= 1:
    blacks[i * 2] = blacks[i * 2]+4
    blacks[(i * 2) + 1] = blacks[(i * 2)+1] - 2
```

Comment: @emsimpson92 No they were not. You misread my original post. I had a right parentheses before the colon at the end, which you misquoted here. Regardless, I've removed the extra left parentheses in my edit since the parentheses is unneeded anyway. By the way, the code by the OP does miss a parentheses, so that's the obvious cause of error, before anything can even run.

Comment: ok, thank you all for the help I guess it was just a distraction